# prove $\sup X \le \sup Y$ if $X$ is a subset of $Y$ both sets are nonempty and $Y$ is bounded above

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Working through foundations of mathematical anlysis by johnsonbaugh per suggestion and wondering if the following proof works? (no solutions to book)

**Problem**:

Let *X* and *Y* be nonempty subsets of real numbers such that $X \subset Y$ and *Y* is bounded above. Prove that $\mathop{\mathrm{sup}} X \le \mathop{\mathrm{sup}} Y$.

**Proof**:

Given that *Y* is bounded above, by the least upper bound axiom there exists a least upper bound of *Y*. Given that $X \subset Y$ we have that $(\forall x \in X)(x \in Y)$. Then, since *Y* is bounded above, *X* must be and we have the existence of a least upper bound for *X*. Now, by definition of a supremum for every upper bound, $a \in Y$, $a\ \le \mathop{\mathrm{sup}} Y$. Hence, for every upper bound $b \in X$, we must have that $b \le \mathop{\mathrm{sup}} Y$ and it follows that $\mathop{\mathrm{sup}} X \le \mathop{\mathrm{sup}} Y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last bit is confused. You know that $\sup(Y)$ exists and is an upper bound for $X$ as well, as $X \subseteq Y$. So $\sup(X)$ exists. But $\sup(X)$ is the smallest of all upperbounds of $X$, and $\sup(Y)$ is one of the possible upper bounds. So..

Comment: Not sure I follow $\mathop{\mathrm{sup}} Y$ is one of the possible upper bounds.. So, since $\mathop{\mathrm{sup}} X$ is the smallest of all upper bounds of X and $\mathop{\mathrm{sup}} Y$ is a possible upper bound it must be less than $\mathop{\mathrm{sup}} X$ by definition of $\mathop{\mathrm{sup}} X$ if im following? I thought that's what my last line stated?

Comment: Yes, but that was not what I read

Comment: @Slayer $\sup Y$ is an upper bound for $Y$. Then $X\subseteq Y$ implies that it is an upper bound of $X$ as well. That implies directly that $\sup Y$ will not be smaller than the least upper bound of $X$. So $\sup X\leq \sup Y$.

Comment: You said "Now, by definition of a supremum for every upper bound, $a \in Y$,  $a \le \sup Y$", which makes no sense.

Comment: Okay now I see my error I didn't see it at first. That makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be able to help!